# Best solution to connect 11 3.5" SATA disks (HDD) to Linux in term of hardware

Tags: storage, hardware

I would like to connect 11 SATA 3.5" (majors 4TB some 3TB) HDD to the same processing unit (same Linux system). I plan to use debian on amd64. Use would be a cloud storage server.

I didn't find something reliable as now, multiple PCI Express to SATA cards are offered everywhere but they are not reliable as i seen on the comments. Maybe use a old SAS controler to manage connect all disks through SAS to SATA cable ? (i don't feel confident using this kind of cable).

I would really appreciate your help since i may have soon the SATA disks to use for this. Classic PC motherboards (that's what i will maybe retain) are up to 6 SATA ports, since i would like to plug 11 SATA disks it can do the job for 6 disks but i don't have the solution for the 5 others.

Thanks to community

Comment: if they're unreliable buy a better brand. also make sure your power supply is strong enough!

Comment: Using "classic PC motherboards" for something like this is probably not going to work well.  As @Jasen noted, there's a real good chance the power supply won't be able to run your system.  Just poke around a certain auction site and search for things like "Supermicro X8DT3".  Even a really old 2U server with space for 12 3.5" drives would work a lot better than an old desktop system.

Comment: I didn't find reliables PCIE to SATA cards. "Supermicro X8DT3" doesnt fill my needs and is to old. I can maybe recycle a Intel I5 5th GEN with a ATX card but i don't know if can connect my drives with PCIE to SATA adapters or old SAS controler with SAS to SATA cable. I have like 200$ budget.

Comment: @BenjaminH *"Supermicro X8DT3" doesnt fill my needs and is to old* What are your needs?  What are your sustained and peak IOPS?  How much storage do you need?  How are you going to back this up? If don't know any of that, you can't know if any hardware proposed can or can not meet you needs. And do you really think something like an old 2U Supermicro storage server can't keep up with a mere 11 **S-L-O-W** SATA drives?  Even though that's what it was designed to do?

Comment: You might try to get ahold of some SATA Port Multipliers.  There are at least some relatively cheap external SATA docking bays that a built in PMP and slots for two drives.

Comment: @psusi Port multipliers only solve the "where do the wires connect" problem.  The (likely crappy) motherboard-based SATA controller might not work with port multipliers, and where do the 11 drives actually go?  Do they hang in the air by their cables?  Where does the power for the drives come from?  How much time will it take to cobble together an unreliable solution that's likely to literally fall apart if the janitor's vacuum runs into the table it's laying on?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't need highs IOPS since the software that i use to export my volume to the cloud is only cold storage. Absolutely not designed for highs IOPS.. Unfortunately.. I dream about other than cold storage but i didn't know reliable platform who purpose other than cold object storage. Power may come from ~500W modular ATX Gold power-unit with multiple SATA power cables. If needed i can easily replace components. I have a small budget who don't permit me to invest more than 200$-250$

Comment: @psusi i look for SATA Port Multiplier and i didn't find anything reliable, but i will continue.

Comment: A "cold storage"? And "Supermicro X8DT3 doesn't full your needs"? These are mutually exclusive statements, please pick only one. Supermicro X8DT3 will perfectly support a cold storage, and not just for 11 drives. It may do much more than just that.

Comment: I have to find a motherboard which accept SATA Port Multiplier technology and to find also a great and reliable SATA port multiplier card/interface. Thank you so much dear all.

Comment: All SATA controllers can accept a PMP, though they might only be able to use it in the simple mode instead of the better performing FIS switching mode.  A quick search on amazon turned this up: https://www.amazon.com/Zer-one-Multiplier-Motherboard-Expansion/dp/B07WHNX8MP/ref=sr_1_4?crid=3R7DNANS5CA2I&dchild=1&keywords=sata+port+multiplier&qid=1614199226&sprefix=sata+port+mult%2Caps%2C170&sr=8-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i have wrote here some people answer me and i would like to thanks thoses persons first. The solution the most reliable is to invest into server stuff, a server motherboard like Supermicro X8DT3 which have pcie x8 ports and to plug LSI Controller Card SAS 9211-8i IT Mode 8 Port 6Gb/s connected (pcie x8) to IBM ServeRAID 6g SAS Expander FRU 46m0997 (pcie x8) (via 2x SAS SFF 8088 to SFF 8088 on the input ports) + 3*SFF-8087 SATA Cable to connect up to 12 drives through one LSI Controller Card.  Thanks to the community.

Answer (score 1):

"Reasonable information technology management practices" would suggest that you purchase server hardware for such a machine, in which case connecting tens of disks to a single server is a solved problem, often done via HBA interfaces.

Comment: i flag your question for superuser as this question doea not fit for business purposes only. use a hba or raid card if you not willing to buy, then you are here on the wrong platform. Linux could handle hundreds of drives without to care about

Comment: I don't know if i will find users who know RAID cards into superuser ?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, you won't find people here who'll understand your homemade requirements. People here have a habit to build systems like a tank, which could be supported for years.

That's because information is most valuable we ever have in the computer, so we manage it very carefully. And your question seems like you are quite careless.

Nevertheless, I have one suggestion. Consider SATA **port multipliers** to expand ports of the machine; I've seen devices up to 5 ports. With 6-port controller it'll be possible to connect at most 30 disks (you can't  connect a multiplier to a multiplier). This technology is present in the SATA spec from the very beginning; though, it's rarely used. Test that; it could be your controller won't support that.

That [was used by BackBlaze](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/), I don't see why you need to reinvent the wheel. Notice they use huge amount of power! Also speed will suffer, because you'll have a port speed shared by all devices behind a mupltiplier connected to that port; but HDD is unable to saturate a SATA link, even 4 HDDs are unable to saturate it. But don't try to connect SSDs that way, they will crawl like HDDs.

I don't get why you refuse to try old Supermicro platform. Yes, it's old, but it has pretty enough processing power to manage a storage array of 11 hard drives and make it accessbile through a network to some computing machine. Such platform knows HDDs well and won't start them simultaneously, so power spike problem will be relieved; such platform will have a easy to access drive bay, so you'll thank the day when you decided to buy that when you have need to identify "which one" needs to be removed and replaced. And so on. Please understand, when you grow, from certain point you simply can't continue to use old techniques, they don't scale so well. And I am pretty sure 11 drives is quite a number to rethink and to not to manage them like 2 drives of home computer with desktop mobo.

Comment: Hello Nikita, thank you very much for your reference, i did not know previously BlackBlaze project but right now i know it ! I will look for this kind of SATA ports multipliers and i have to find a motherboard which accept this technology. I had also project to construct my enclosure for 2-3U rack capacity. This project consist only of cold storage with HDDs. I will keep you informed on this topic. Take care, Regards, Benjamin

Comment: I humbly remind BackBlaze is one of leading providers of cloud backup storage, not just a "project". Now you know how the cloud storage is built (this is just a tiny brick of their huge castle, however).